# Unable to download youtube video

Tags: ubuntu, youtube-dl

I don't know what happened now but I'm unable to download any youtube video. Earlier it was working properly. I'm working on Ubuntu 13.04

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONWvX8ESrsk
[youtube] Setting language
[youtube] ONWvX8ESrsk: Downloading video webpage
[youtube] ONWvX8ESrsk: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] ONWvX8ESrsk: Extracting video information
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl/__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl/__init__.py", line 536, in main
  File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl/__init__.py", line 520, in _real_main
  File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl/FileDownloader.py", line 475, in download
  File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl/InfoExtractors.py", line 80, in extract
  File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl/InfoExtractors.py", line 405, in _real_extract
  File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl/InfoExtractors.py", line 405, in <genexpr>
KeyError: 'sig'
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$
```

Comment: Have you thought to update your `youtube-dl` tool ?

Comment: There should be more recent versions of this script packaged for your distribution. Just upgrade to those. This script has no depedencies to speak of, so a backport should not be necessary. The current version in Debian is 2014.02.17-1. What version are you running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `youtube-dl` script comes with its own update mechanism. Simply run this to update it:

```
$ youtube-dl -U
```

See the help (`--help`):

```
-U, --update        update this program to latest version. Make sure 
                    that you have sufficient permissions (run with sudo if 
                    needed)
```

This is a little cat and mouse game that users of this script have to periodically update the script, because YouTube breaks the ability to download videos from the site.

I would also encourage you to use single/double quotes when passing the URLs to `youtube-dl` via the command line on the off chance that they include unusual characters such as question marks and ampersands. This way, the shell does not interpret those characters!

> Here's a example of using single quotes:
>
> `$ youtube-dl 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONWvX8ESrsk'`

Comment: I think in Ubuntu 13.10, the youtube-dl from the software center cannot be updated by running `sudo youtube-dl -U`. If you get youtube-dl directly from https://yt-dl.org/, it updates perfectly with the command.

Comment: I see that OP is on 13.04. I don't know about that because it is EOL. Whether that will get updates of any software, IDK :(

Comment: Re. unusual characters, at least "basic" YouTube urls look like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=........... where the eleven dots could be `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `-` and `_`. I have not seen other characters. It's quite possible that there may be unusual characters but I haven't seen them as yet. In any case, your advice is safer.

Comment: Here's an example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGyEd0aKWZE&feature=kp. My kids just watched this video "Ellie Goulding - Burn" today and it has an ampersand in it.

Comment: Yes, that comes _after_ the basic url and so quotes would help.

Comment: @DKBose - also the `youtube-dl` script can source media from other sites besides Youtube. These other sites, such as Yahoo do have ampersands, so don't limit your thinking to it only being Youtube URLs.

Comment: That is true. I'm going to fix my youtube-dl alias to accommodate quotes so that I just paste in the url with a closing `'`.

Comment: I know this b/c my kids are always asking to d/l music from these video services and I've been burned by it a lot 8-)

Comment: If it's just the music, you may want to look at http://www.webupd8.org/2014/02/video-downloader-youtube-dl-gets.html though it isn't perfect.

Comment: I use it like so for audio: `youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 0 ...`.

Comment: Doesn't that need downloading of the video first? The webupd8 does it without downloading the video.

Comment: @DKBose - Yes I believe so, I just tried the `-F` & `-f` options and see that they download the format directly.

Comment: Thanks slm. Great! It has worked. Sorry for late reply as now only I checked this.

Comment: @Ravi - glad that solved your issue, please mark this as accepted so everyone knows the issue's been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

> [mps-youtube](https://github.com/np1/mps-youtube) is a new tool which, besides being able to download
>   YouTube videos (either the whole video or just the audio), can also
>   search and play YouTube videos and create local playlists, all from
>   the command line.

Installation

Install pip

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Then install mps-youtube using pip:

```
sudo pip install mps-youtube
```

You'll also need mplayer

```
sudo apt-get install mplayer
```

**Usage**

To run mps-youtube, use the following command:

```
mpsyt
```

To search for a video on YouTube, prefix your search with either "." or "/".

Example: to search for "pantera", use:

```
.pantera
```

[A full tutorial can be found here](https://github.com/np1/mps-youtube)

Answer (score 1):

Update `youtube-dl` by adding this PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

Then you may download any video as usual. For example:

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ix1rD4JD3eo
```

**Note:** It still could be downloaded using [`pip`](https://pypi.org/project/pip/). It is OS independent!

Answer (score 1):

For me the following lines worked:

```
sudo apt-get remove -y youtube-dl
wget -O - https://yt-dl.org/latest/youtube-dl | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl > /dev/null
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
hash -r
```